# Asp.net contact form not submitting value properly

Tags: asp.net

My website have contact form where customer fill their details and send contact details and message for that I use domain email to send filled details to my inbox. Form working good but the issue is when details come to my inbox its look like: Name - 5a313471b73da, mobile No.'blank' etc.

And one more thing it is working for my country, all details come to my inbox as it but when submit from other country then this issue is coming...

here is my code...

```
              //Gmail Address from where you send the mail
                var fromAddress = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FromEmailId"].ToString();
                // any address where the email will be sending
                var toAddress = "email";
                //Password of your gmail address
                string fromPassword = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FromPwd"].ToString();
                // Passing the values and make a email formate to display
                string subject = "Enquiry";

                // smtp settings
                MailMessage Msg = new MailMessage();
                MailAddress fromMail = new MailAddress(fromAddress);
                // Sender e-mail address.
                Msg.From = fromMail;
                // Recipient e-mail address.
                Msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("email"));
                // Subject of e-mail
                Msg.Subject = "Enquiry";
                string body = "Name - " + name.Text.ToString() + "\n";
                body += "Email Id -" + emailId.Text.ToString() + "\n";
                body += "Contact No -" + Phone.Text.ToString() + "\n";
                body += "Subject -" + Subject.Text.ToString() + "\n";
                body += "Message -" + message.Text.ToString() + "\n";



                Msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

                var smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
                {
                    smtp.Host = "smtpout.secureserver.net";
                    smtp.Port = 3535;                   
                    smtp.EnableSsl = false;
                    // smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                    smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                    smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress, fromPassword);
                    smtp.Timeout = 200000;

                }

                smtp.Send(fromAddress, toAddress, subject, body);
```

Comment: Can you please share your code so that we can help

Comment: you have to format content in you email body before send it. create a different class and format body using html tags and send that content. Better if you can provide your code.

Comment: I guess that you use an encryption algorithms on your data. please trace the values as a test user and check them before sending the email. If they are in a format you want, check the value which you pass to sending email function and actually it was better if you attach your codes in your question.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion,

Comment: I think this problem is just because of your data and not is caused by your algorithm. Do you have any java script on your form? Perhaps the java set another values for name and other fields when you select another country! and also make sure that name, phone and other in your method is the correct Ids of your controls on the form.

Comment: hello Golnaz, thanks for your suggestion, i have already done this but not working.